# Joomla. Virtuemart. Не добавляется товар в корзину с главной страницы

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Не добавляет товар в корзину с главной страницы. На первый взгляд страница просто обновляется, но название страницы меняется: "Корзина покупателя". На других страницах все работает, выскакивает окно об успешном добавлении.

Joomla! 3.6.5 Stable
Virtuemart 3

P.S. Если посмотреть в firebug, то он вроде как не видит обработчик нажатия, т.е. функцию в файле vmprices.js, хотя он подключен.

Answer (score 0):

На главной странице стоят какие-нибудь доп модули от других компонентов? Что-то, что добавляет новые скрипты?
Посмотрите порядок подгрузки скриптов на главной странице и на других страницах.
Скорей всего конфликты js скриптов